# NetworkStream truncates my data?

Tags: c#, file, task, .net-4.5, networkstream

On the same computer I have  2 console applications. (client sends a file to server)

Before I start I just want to mention that i'm using those 2 `async` functions  :

*For reading from `NetworkStream`:*

```
 public static Task<int> ReadAsync1(this NetworkStream networkStream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
   {
     return Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(networkStream.BeginRead, networkStream.EndRead, buffer, offset, buffer.Length, networkStream);
   }
```

*For writing to `NetworkStream`:*

```
   public static Task WriteAsync1(this NetworkStream networkStream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
    {
      return Task.Factory.FromAsync(networkStream.BeginWrite, networkStream.EndWrite, buffer, offset, buffer.Length, networkStream);
    }
```

**My client code** :

*(let's take a simple file which I know it's size)*

[image]

My code for sending:

```
 NetworkStream ns = socketForServer.GetStream();
 ns.WriteAsync1(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\r\1.jpg"), 0, 1593899);
 ns.Flush();
```

**My Server code** : (reading...)

```
byte[] d = new byte[1593899];
networkStream.Read(d, 0, d.Length);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\r\2.jpg",d);
```

Result :

`2.jpg` is written :

[image]

So where is the problem ?

`2.jpg` is corrupted ! When I try to open the image I see this :

[image]

(instead of a the same image as `1.jpg`)

So I went to see   the "HEX" for what is wrong :

I found out that after a while -all  it writes are zeros :

<sup>[larger iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOJan.png)</sup>

[image]

**Question**

What am I doing wrong ? And how can I fix the code so it will send the whole file ?

Comment: Not sure if that's it, but you seem to be ignoring the `size` parameter to `WriteAsync1`.

Comment: The `Stream` class already has perfectly good `ReadAsync()` and `WriteAsync()` methods. It is absurd to write whole new ones. As for the question, this is almost certainly being caused by the fact that you assume incorrectly that a single read operation will return all of the data you need. It won't; you have to check the return value of the read operation (which is the count of bytes _actually_ read) and then take the appropriate reaction (e.g. read more data or, once the right number of bytes has been read, go on to actually process the data).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Wow. I didn't notice ( it happens) that it already has ReadAsync. but it still yields corrupted image

Comment: according  to msdn  the buffer size  of Networkstream  is 8192 k. If the file size is greater than this then you file a will be corrupted. Use the read  method  of the stream  and keep reading  from the stream  until read is greater than zero.

Comment: Yes, of course it yields corrupted data. That bug isn't because you reimplemented the async methods; it's because you're incorrectly assuming that a single read operation gets all of the data and ignoring the byte count value returned by the read operation.

Comment: @user3514987: even if the file size is less than 8KB (the default receive buffer for a `Socket`...not sure where you got "8192 k" from), you can still receive less than the entire file in a single receive. The buffer is an upper bound for how much data can be buffered, not a guarantee of how much data _will_ be buffered before it's delivered to a read operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your client code does not finish reading the entire content: you should have a loop that reads to the end before checking the content:

```
int remaining = d.Length;
int pos = 0;
while (remaining != 0) {
    int add = networkStream.Read(d, pos, remaining);
    pos += add;
    remaining -= add;
}
```

Currently, your code reads as much data as the network stream chooses to make initially available to you, and stop without retrieving the rest of the bytes.

Comment: But what if the buffer is exactly as the size of my data ? doesn't it reads as much as the buffer size ?

Comment: Are you sure ? about `remaining = d.Length` and `networkStream.Read(d`  ??one suppose to be the buffer , the other suppose to be size?

Comment: @RoyiNamir : If you look at the docs for `Stream.Read`, you'll see that it returns a value "actual bytes read". Only when this returns `0` can you be certain that you have read the entire stream. You should always use the returned value to see how much you have read. Given that the default buffer length for `NetworkStream` is 8192 (IIRC), you're never going to get a single read larger than this value. Never assume you read what you requested. The return value is what you need to look at.

Comment: `Stream.Read` returns "The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Just to check : I don't need this attitude with `Write` right ? the problem is only with Read...right? ( I mean  - I don't need write in some kind of loop right )?

Comment: @RoyiNamir You're good on the writing side. You don't need to call `Flush` either, [because it has no effect on `NetweorkStream`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

It's not good idea to read all bytes at once. You should read data by blocks, something like this:

```
buffer = new byte[4096];
int offset = 0;
do {
  int read = networkStream.Read(buffer, offset, buffer.Length - offset);
  offset += read;
} while (read != 0);
```